# Nested input fields (parent and child structure)

Tags: php, webforms, parent-child

I am in a real tricky situation where I have a page that allows records to be inputted and there is a parent/child structure (or records/sub-records if you call it). Many records/sub-records can be added dynamically (the rows are cloned and inserted after the next row) when the user needs to add more.

**The structure**:

```
<div class="row">
   <strong>Parent record:</strong> <input type="text" name="parent-record[]" />
   <div class="row">
       <strong>Child record:</strong> <input type="text" name="child-record[]" />
   </div>
   <span class="add-subrecord">Add another sub-record</span>
</div>
<span class="add-record">Add another record</span>
```

The problem on the PHP side, when I have 2 for loops, 1 in a for loop like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['parent-record']); $i++)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO records (input) VALUES ('" . $_POST['parent-record'][$i] . "')";
    $result = $db->sql_query($sql);

    $parent_id = $db->sql_nextid(); // mysql_insert_id

    for($j = 0; $j < count($_POST['child-record']); $j++)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO records (input, parent) VALUES('" . $_POST['child-record'][$j] . "', '" . $parent_id . "')"; // this will also insert the $parent_id into this record because this record is a child of a parent.
        $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
    }
}
```

However, when the process has done, each child has a parent of the *first* main record, even when I add 2-3 *main* records (not child records) so like:

```
+------+---------+----------+
| id   | input   | parent   |
+------+---------+----------+
| 1    | random  | 0        | <- indicates it is a parent
| 2    | random1 | 1        | <- child record, parent is record id: 1
| 3    | random2 | 1        | <- child record, parent is record id: 1
| 4    | random3 | 1        | <- this should be a parent, but it's added as a child
| 5    | random4 | 1        | <- this one too
+------+---------+----------+
```

I need some kind of solution how this will work when creating nested input form that all child have a parent id of the record block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in the way in which you are iterating over the records.  You start by inserting the first parent record.  Then, you iterate over *all* child records--*including* the child records that belong to different parents.  For example, take the following user input:

```
parent1
  child1a
  child1b
parent2
  child2a
```

This will generate the following $_POST array:

```
$_POST['parent-record'] = array('parent1', 'parent2');
$_POST['child-record'] = array('child1a', 'child1b', 'child2a');
```

So, you can see that, after you insert `parent1` into the database, you then insert all the child records, which incorrectly assigns `parent1` as `child2a`'s parent.

You need a way of determining which children belong to what parent.

**AND REMEMBER** to encode your user input before inserting it into a SQL query!!

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO records (input) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['parent-record'][$i]) . "')";
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how I can implement a sorting feature somehow... *I know about cleaning inputs - it was just a demo of code*

Comment: @lolwut You could add a unique number to the names of each group.  For example, the first parent would be named "parent-record-0".  The children of "parent-record-0" would have names "child-record-0-0", "child-record-0-1", etc.

Comment: @lolwut Actually, the child records could be arrays.  So, the first parent would be named "parent-record-0" and its child records would be named "child-record-0[]".  The second parent would be named "parent-record-1" and its child records would be named "child-record-1[]". Etc.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can change the names for the form inputs in this way:

```
<div class="row">
  <strong>Parent record:</strong> <input type="text" name="parent-record[1]" />
  <div class="row">
    <strong>Child record:</strong> <input type="text" name="parent-record[1]child-record[]" />
  </div>
  <span class="add-subrecord">Add another sub-record</span>
</div>
<span class="add-record">Add another record</span>
```

I'm assuming you're using javascript to add new inputs. You can use the names as above but increment the number.

In the PHP post array each parent should have an array of child records.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the last part of your code:

```
for($j = 0; $j < count($_POST['child-record']); $i++)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO records (input, parent) VALUES('" . $_POST['child-record'][$j] . "', '" . $parent_id . "')"; // this will also insert the $parent_id into this record because this record is a child of a parent.
        $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
    }
```

I think it should be:

```
 for($j = 0; $j < count($_POST['child-record']); $j++)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO records (input, parent) VALUES('" . $_POST['child-record'][$j] . "', '" . $parent_id . "')"; // this will also insert the $parent_id into this record because this record is a child of a parent.
        $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
    }
```

j++ instead of i++